# Разбор по составу слова "Отпиваешь"

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Понятно, что от- — приставка. А вот дальше начинаются вопросы. Какой корень (*пив*, *пи*, *п*)? Какой суффикс?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Встречал различные варианты разбора, в том числе и варианты, где выделяются два корня (*пи* и *ва*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отпивать — приставка **от-**, корень **-пи-**, суффикс **-ва**, глагольное окончание **-ть**.

В морфемно-орфографическом словаре [А. Тихонова](http://www.slovorod.ru/der-tikhonov/tih-o.htm):
отпивать | от/пи/ва́/ть (от *от/пи́/ть*).

В словообразовательном словаре современного русского языка [О. Ульяновой](https://books.google.ee/books?id=rQWiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA338&lpg=PA338&dq=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=_09HY6D6dO&sig=ACfU3U3iGyX7ZDbtw9ubAxi8gOyM0AkDyQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiyrruH_uzoAhXl-ioKHXEHClMQ6AEwAHoECAwQKg#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5&f=false):
пить — от-пи́ть — отпи-ва́-ть.

*Ты* (что дела**ешь**?) *отпива́**ешь*** (наст. время, 2 лицо, ед. ч.) — окончание **-ешь.**

Answer (score 2):

Пить — от-пить. Есть приставка от-.

Отпить — отпи-ва-ть. Есть суффикс -ва-.

Отпивать — отпива-ешь (отпива-ет, отпива-ют). Есть окончание -ешь.

Итого: от-пи-ва-ешь.

Answer (score 0):

С интересом прочитал варианты разбора слова по составу, но почему-то не обнаружил варианта с корнем -п-,  а ведь на эту мысль наталкивает однокоренное слово "отопью"